# Start, stop, configure PostgreSQL through Mac terminal

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, postgresql-9.5

I am having basic problems using PostgreSQL on my Mac OSX Yosemite, through the terminal. I tried google-ing but this is becoming increasingly difficult and info very scattered so I keep running into walls.

I did the following:

1. installed PostgreSQL 9.5.2 via **Homebrew**
2. modified my shell config file (**.zshrc**) to include PostgreSQL bin directory in $PATH variable
3. I did the "**initdb**" routine and "told" Postgres that I want to store my databases in `/usr/local/cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/data`

**Here I tried starting postgreSQL:**

```
$pg_ctl /usr/local/cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/data -l logfile start
```

**first error:**

> pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
>
> /bin/sh: logfile: Permission denied

As far as I understand, I am trying to start the PostgreSQL server and direct its output and errors into a log file, located in a location for which my user has no write privileges.

How can I fix this?

Here I tried stopping the server and try again:

```
$pg_ctl -D /usr/local/cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/data stop
```

This worked ok. So,

- How can I use other location to start the server and enable log
- How do I check if the server is running if I need to stop it (if errors appear)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error indcates the server is already running.  Have you tried connecting with psql or run the following to establish that?

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/data status
```

If you know it is down, then for the second error with the logfile on startup, either reissue the command with an absolute path to where you can write a file:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/data -l /tmp/logfile start
```

Or if that doesn't work for you, try starting without the -l switch:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/data start
```

Without the switch, you still get the PostgreSQL logs in the pg_log directory under the $PGDATA - in your case /usr/local/cellar/postgresql/9.5.2/data/pg_log

Answer (score 3):

To add on the previous answer - worth mentioning that in my case (Postgres 10/MacOS X High Sierra) the data storage location (the path at -D option) was different: `/Library/PostgreSQL/10/data`

So e.g. to stop the server I used:

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/10/data stop
```

Or the same command using the `postgres` user's home directory (which might be more universal for future versions):

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_ctl -D ~/data stop
```

Starting/checking status is similar (just use `start` or `status` instead of `stop`)